# HTML Table to XLS (Cell used for a formula)

Tags: php, html, excel, html-table

I am doing an HTML table and I want it to be converted to XLS file

I am using this table for example

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>EUR</td>
        <td>300.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>AUD</td>
        <td>**=SUM(A2:A10);**</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way how I can create a cell with the  `=SUM(A2:A10);` as a formula and not a normal plain text?

Comment: Take a look at [PHPExcel Library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I cannot use another library as now the excel is 95% ready I just need to run a total at the end of the excel... But the sum has a lot of conditions.

Comment: Then you should tell us what library you're using, what interfaces it provides, and what's the exact problem with assigning a formula to cell value.

Comment: I am using absolutely no library... I am getting the above mentioned HTML and then is saving it to a file with the extension .xls and then it opens via Excel as a normal XLS SHEET.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When importing html to excel, it is important to know that there are a variety of excel-specific attributes that you can use to get excel to perform pretty much like you would expect it to, for nearly any business requirement.

You'll need the excel namespaces added:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
</html>
```

And then you can create a formula in a table cell:

```
<td x:num x:fmla="=SUM(A2,A10)">0</td>
```

You can read much more about properly implementing these capabilities in this article:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

replace

```
<tr>
<td>AUD</td><td>**=SUM(A2:A10);**</td>
</tr>
```

with

```
<tr>
<td>AUD</td><td>=SUM(A2:A10)</td>
</tr>
```