# Html table to Excel: formulas

Tags: html, excel, html-table

I am a newbie on Html and Excel. I am trying to open an html file with Excel 
I need to add formulas in my table. I read this topic [HTML Table to XLS (Cell used for a formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108757/html-table-to-xls-cell-used-for-a-formula)

This line works :

```
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#F2F2F2<b><font color=#FF8000>=((1000 * M6) / (C6 * 3.14))</font></b>
```

but this line not :

```
<td x:num x:fmla="=((1000 * M6) / (C6 * 3.14))">0</td>
```

If I open my Excel file, enter my formula, the lines are offset , like this :

```
=((1000 * M11) / (C11 * 3.14))
```

I don’t know where my mistake is... below my code :

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<TABLE BORDER=1>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=2 ><FONT >LO</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=6><FONT >TYPE</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=3><FONT >REF </FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=3><FONT >OP: </FONT></th>
</table>
<TABLE BORDER=1>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=1><FONT >NR</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=7><FONT >FR</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=3><FONT >Date: 30/Nov/2020</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=LEFT BGCOLOR=#FFEB9C WIDTH=20% COLSPAN=3><FONT >F1:</FONT></th>
</table>
<BR>
<table>
<th ALIGN=LEFT WIDTH=50%><FONT COLOR=999999>9999</FONT></th>
</table>
<tr>
<CENTER><table WIDTH=700 BORDER=1>
<tr ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=CENTER>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=20%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C1</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C2</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C3</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C4</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C5</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C6</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C7</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C8</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C9</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C10</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C11</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C12</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C13</FONT></th>
<th ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A4A4A4 WIDTH=10%><FONT COLOR=#190707>C14</FONT></th>
</tr>
</table>
<table border=1>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A9F5A9>1</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A9F5A9>TOOL1</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A9F5A9>25.0000</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A9F5A9>0.8000</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A9F5A9>24.8000</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#A9F5A9>-</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#81DAF5>60.0 mini</td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#81DAF5></td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#81DAF5></td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#81DAF5></td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#81DAF5></td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#81DAF5></td>
<td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#F2F2F2 <b><font color=#FF8000>0</font></b>
<!-- M  6 C 6 -->
<!-- <td ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR=#F2F2F2<b><font color=#FF8000>=((1000 * M6) / (C6 * 3.14))</font></b> -->
<td x:num x:fmla="=((1000 * M6) / (C6 * 3.14))">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: If you change the M6 & C6  in "<td x:num x:fmla="=((1000 * M6) / (C6 * 3.14))">0</td>" to $M$6 & $C$6 will the outcome be the same?

Comment: @p._phidot_ thanks, same thing... I think I’m not using the <table> tag in the right way.

Comment: after a test.. 'manually' offset by -5 results in C6 & M6 . the code I used : `<td x:num x:fmla="=((1000 * M1) / (C1 * 3.14))">0</td>` || [ -5 = 6 -11 ] I'm not sure if this manual offset solves your need. but that is what I tried and it just work.

Comment: @p._phidot_ , yes with manual offset It works , but it's not the solution what I'm looking for...thanks anyway